# Get Bounce back information of a lead in salesforce marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there a way i can get the bounce back information of a lead through an API from marketing cloud?
Please note: The lead can be in data extension or in List and the email is send through the journey builders.

Basically, i want to get information about Soft & hard bounce back information of a lead.

Comment: REST API, query Dataview _Bounce, it contains (mostly) 6month of bounce data.

Comment: You can also use ENS aka web hooks for engagement data

Comment: Why not use the standard Marketing Cloud Connect tracking objects?